# Singapore transit visa for multiple PNR

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, singapore, canadian-permanent-residents

I am travelling from India to Canada via Singapore.
However, I have booked two separate tickets, one from India to Singapore, the other from Singapore to Canada. I did this to save some money on the ticket. I don't have any intention to leave the airport.

Do I have to apply for a Singapore visa if I have a layover of 4 hours in Singapore, but separate tickets (different PNR)? Will there be a port of entry in Singapore? Will a Singapore visa be asked when boarding the flight in India?

I hold an Indian passport with Canadian Permanent Resident Card. I also hold a US tourist visa.

Comment: Will you have checked bags?

Answer (score 7):

You should be eligible for the Visa-Free Transit Facility (VFTF), staying up to 96 hours.

> Nationals of India and the PRC
>
> If you are in transit to or from any third country via Singapore, you
> may be eligible for the 96-hour VFTF if you meet these requirements:
>
> You may enter Singapore by any mode of transport but depart only via air or sea. You must have a valid onward air/ferry/cruise ticket
> departing Singapore within 96 hours; and
>
> You must have a valid visa* or long-term pass (with a validity of at least one month from the date of entry into Singapore under the
> VFTF) issued by and/or good for entry into any of the following
> countries:
>
> - Australia
> - Canada
> - Germany
> - Japan
> - New Zealand
> - Switzerland
> - United Kingdom
> - United States of America

Source: https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-transit-depart/entering-singapore/visa-free-transit-facility

Comment: While I agree that Singapore will let them in, they are at the mercy of the first airline to let them board, and trying to do this with separate tickets is IMHO quite risky.  I would get a visa to be sure.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Print the web page of ICA out and hand it to the staff when checking-in. In fact I see a higher risk of the first flight being delayed and can't catch the second one, than being prevented boarding from India.

Comment: Airline policy and TIMATIC will trump random printouts.

Comment: Printouts are to inform the existence of VFTF to airline staff in case they don't know about it. They of course will check TIMATIC or their own policies to make decision.

Answer (score 3):

I have done many similar transfers in Singapore without issue. It all relies on the airlines involved – if they interline (even if they're not in the same alliance) as full-service airlines in Asia do, you can chek in your luggage all the way through. All you need is both boarding passes. If the airlines interline, you might be able to get both right from the start, or in Singapore at the Transfer Desk. Enquire with both airlines about interlining and the Transfer Desk/boarding pass.

On the other hand, if you are flying with at least one LCC, or the airlines don't interline, forget about it, you'll have to pick up your luggage in Singapore, go upstairs and check in again. As an Indian citizen with an onward ticket, you are eligible for the [Visa-Free Transit Facility](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-transit-depart/entering-singapore/visa-free-transit-facility). This will allow you to do that. The only issue is how much time you have between flights – and keep in mind the first flight could be delayed.